# Cannot redeclare function error on the same line

Tags: plugin-development

I'm getting this error when cart page loads (plugin is designed to work for cart page only):

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare custom_cart_min_qty() (previously declared in

```
/home/platne/serwer24774/public_html/staging/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin-slug/my-plugin-slug.php:199) in

/home/platne/serwer24774/public_html/staging/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin-slug/my-plugin-slug.php on line 199
```

It looks like my code executes twice. How can I prevent it the proper way, without only checking whether function is defined? Is it connected to me creating new class instance on page load perhaps?

I edited some irrelevant lines and descriptions to made this long code somewhat easier to inspect, mentioned function is now in different line.

`acau_setting_2` is settings page checkbox value which if checked, causes `custom_cart_min_qty()` function to execute.

```
<?php

// If this file is called directly, abort.
if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
    die;
}

// Create settings class.
class my_plugin_name_settings
{   
    private $options;   
    private $settings_page_name;
    private $settings_menu_name;

    public function __construct()
    {               
        $this->settings_page_name = 'my-plugin-slug';
        $this->settings_menu_name = 'My Plugin Name';   

        // Initialize and register settings. 
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'register_settings' ) );
        // Add settings page.
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_settings_page' ) );
        // Add settings link to plugins page.
        add_action( 'plugin_action_links_' . plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), array( $this, 'add_settings_link' ) );
    }

    public function register_settings()
    {   
        register_setting( 'acau_settings', 'acau_settings', array( $this, 'sanitize' ) );

        // ID / title / callback / page
        add_settings_section( 'configuration_section', __( 'Configuration', 'my-plugin-slug' ), array( $this, 'print_section_info' ), $this->settings_page_name );

        // ID / title / callback / page / section
        add_settings_field( 'acau_setting_1', __( 'Irrelevant setting with integer value', 'my-plugin-slug' ), array( $this, 'acau_setting_1_callback' ), $this->settings_page_name, 'configuration_section' );
        add_settings_field( 'acau_setting_2', __( 'Cart minimum quantity', 'my-plugin-slug' ), array( $this, 'acau_setting_2_callback' ), $this->settings_page_name, 'configuration_section' );     

    }

    public function add_settings_page()
    {
        // This page will be under "Settings"
        add_options_page(
            'Settings Admin', $this->settings_menu_name, 'manage_options', $this->settings_page_name, array( $this, 'create_settings_page' )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the option that is saved or the default.
     *
     * @param string $index. The option we want to get.
     */
    public function acau_get_settings( $index = false ) {
        $defaults = [ 'acau_setting_1' => 1000,'acau_setting_2' => true ];
        $settings = get_option( 'acau_settings', $defaults );
        $settings = wp_parse_args( $settings, $defaults );

        if ( $index && isset( $settings[ $index ] ) ) {
            return $settings[ $index ];
        }

        return $settings;
    }

    public function create_settings_page()
    {      
        $this->options = $this->acau_get_settings();        

        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h1>My Plugin Name</h1>
            <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php
                // This prints out all hidden setting fields
                settings_fields( 'acau_settings' );
                do_settings_sections( $this->settings_page_name );
                submit_button();
            ?>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    function add_settings_link( $links ) {
        $links = array_merge( array(
            '<a href="' . esc_url( admin_url( '/options-general.php?page=' . $this->settings_page_name ) ) . '">' . __( 'Settings' ) . '</a>'
        ), $links );
        return $links;
    }

    /**
     * Sanitize each setting field as needed
     *
     * @param array $input Contains all settings fields as array keys
     */
    public function sanitize( $input )
    {
        $new_input = array();
        if( isset( $input['acau_setting_1'] ) )
            $new_input['acau_setting_1'] = absint( $input['acau_setting_1'] );
        if( isset( $input['acau_setting_2'] ) )
            $new_input['acau_setting_2'] = ( $input['acau_setting_2'] == 1 ? 1 : 0 );           

        return $new_input;
    }

    /** 
     * Print the Section text
     */

    public function print_section_info()
    {
        return;
        // print 'Enter your settings below:';
    }

    /** 
     * Get the settings option array and print one of its values
     */
    public function acau_setting_1_callback()
    {
        printf(
            '<input type="text" id="acau_setting_1" name="acau_settings[acau_setting_1]" value="%1$s" />
            <p class="description">%2$s</p>',
            isset( $this->options['acau_setting_1'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->options['acau_setting_1']) : '',
            __( 'Irrelevant setting 1 description.', 'my-plugin-slug' )
        );
    }

    public function acau_setting_2_callback() {
        printf(
        '<fieldset>
            <label><input id="acau_setting_2" type="checkbox" name="acau_settings[acau_setting_2]" value="1" %1$s />%2$s</label>
        </fieldset>',
        isset( $this->options['acau_setting_2'] ) && ( 1 == $this->options['acau_setting_2'] )  ? 'checked="checked" ':'',
        __( 'Change minimum product quantity on cart page from 0 to 1.', 'my-plugin-slug' )     
        );
    }

}

if( is_admin() )    
    $my_settings_page = new my_plugin_name_settings();

// Only if WooCommerce is active.
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) || ( get_site_option('active_sitewide_plugins') && array_key_exists( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', get_site_option('active_sitewide_plugins') ) ) ) {

    // Run plugin.
    add_action( 'template_redirect', 'run_plugin' );
    function run_plugin() {

        if (! is_cart() ) return; // Only if it's cart page.

        // Enqueue CSS and js file. Localize to use php variables from plugin settings.
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin_name' );
        function my_plugin_name( ) {

            $plugin_abbv_name = 'acau';
            $plugin_slug = 'my-plugin-slug-for-woocommerce';
            $plugin_short_slug = 'my-plugin-slug';

            wp_enqueue_style( $plugin_short_slug . '-style', plugins_url() . '/' . $plugin_slug . '/css/' . $plugin_slug . '.css');
            wp_enqueue_script( $plugin_short_slug . '-script', plugins_url() . '/' . $plugin_slug . '/js/' . $plugin_slug . '.js', '', array('jquery'));

            $acau_settings_page = new my_plugin_name_settings();

            // js variable name => variable value
            $data = array (
                'acau_setting_1' => $acau_settings_page->acau_get_settings('acau_setting_1'),               
            );      

            wp_localize_script( $plugin_short_slug . '-script', 'phpVars', $data );

            // Cart page minimum qty = 1 instead of 0.              
            if (1 == $acau_settings_page->acau_get_settings('acau_setting_2') ) {               
                add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'custom_cart_min_qty', 10, 2 );
                function custom_cart_min_qty( $args, $product ) {
                   $args['min_value'] = 1;
                   return $args;
                }
            }       

        }   
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't define functions within functions. `function run_plugin()`, `function my_plugin_name()`, and `custom_cart_min_qty()`. This is not how you should write this code. Your `add_action()` and `add_filter` hooks already call these functions.